# How can I get the li-Element in "Angular2 for TypeScript" (beta) for adding specific CSS class?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular

In my Angular2 project I'm trying to implement a searchbox with a resultbox appearing like in Google. That's what I got and it works, but unfortunately when you search something and you press "key down" or "key up" the search result in the resultbox are not highlighting like in Google.

That's my code:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control">

// resultbox
<div>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#item of items">{{ item.text }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Note: "items" is the search result list, which works! The results are finally showing up.

I know you can put in "`<input>`" a (keyup) function, but how should it mark the specific li-element in the resultbox list? 
My idea was something like a index counter. When the index counter is for example 3, then the third li-element should be added with the class "searchIndex", which gives the li-element new color.

But I have no idea how I should do that. Do you have a solution how to do that? Or do yo have a better solution to solve that?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input (keyup)="selected--" (keydown)="selected++">

<div>
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#item of items; #i=index" [class.selected]="i == selected">{{ item.text }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

You need some special handling for `selected < 0` or `selected >= numResult` but that should be easy when you use an event handler function instead of inline `--`/`++`. I guess you get the idea.

**Update** (to answer a question from the comment)

> Just a little question: When I hover the mouse over the list, do you know how to remove the "selected" css property? I want it like in Google: When you use the keyUp and keyDown than the index is marked. But when you hover the mouse over it, than the selected should be removed and only the hover from the mouse should be active

```
<div>
   <ul (mouseover)="mouseover=true"
       (mouseout)="mouseover=false">
     <li *ngFor="#item of items; #i=index" 
         [class.selected]="i == selected && !mouseover">{{ item.text }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Add this field to the component

```
mouseover:boolean = false;
```

Comment: I did same for horizontal, now when the active pointer passes the screen width, it didn't scroll the page. Any help in that would be appreciated.