# html list item selection with arrow keys in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-lists

I am trying to select li's via arrow keys, but am running into issues.

I tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316988/how-can-i-get-the-li-element-in-angular2-for-typescript-beta-for-adding-spec), but my li's never become selected.

For the following code, I'm just trying to get (keydown) to work.

Here is my:

**landingpage.component.html**

```
<div class="searchArea">
  <input type="text" autoComplete="off" (keydown)="keyDown($event)" placeholder={{backgroundPlaceholder.info.placeholderText}} [(ngModel)]="keystroke"
    (ngModelChange)="getKey($event)">
  <div class="results-list">
    <li *ngFor="let list of shows; let i = index" [class.active]="i == {{arrowkeyLocation}}">
      <span class="result">{{list.show}}</span>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

**landingpage.component.ts**

```
arrowkeyLocation = 0;

 keyDown(event) {
   return this.arrowkeyLocation++; 
 }
```

As-is, nothing is selected when I press the downkey. I'm pretty sure the problem lied within my html [class.active], but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

How can I select li elements via the arrow keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to only select the list using arrow key, I think you need to change your `landingpage.component.ts` to something like this:

```
arrowkeyLocation = 0;

keyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38: // this is the ascii of arrow up
                 this.arrowkeyLocation--;
                 break;
        case 40: // this is the ascii of arrow down
                 this.arrowkeyLocation++;
                 break;
    }
}
```

And in your html you need to change `[class.active]="i == {{arrowkeyLocation}}"` to `[class.active]="i == arrowkeyLocation"`.. No need to use `{{` and `}}` there.

Comment: This works! I'd like to add that you will have to add a .selected element in the CSS  with some different properties, in order to see which element you are currently selecting.

Comment: as-in, the default behavior of a list element being highlighted by clicking or tabbing to it, will not occur.

Comment: @samAlvin I did same for horizontal, now when the active pointer passes the screen width, it didn't scroll the page. Any help in that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with what @samAlvin has to say in his answer and I also recommend using an `if` condition which checks if we haven't exceeded the `li` list otherwise the selection would just disappear if user presses the down arrow key and same in case of up arrow key:

```
if (event.keyCode === 40 && this.selectedLiValue < this.shows.length - 1) {
    // Arrow Down
    this.selectedLiValue++;
} else if (event.keyCode === 38 && this.selectedLiValue > 0) {
    // Arrow Up
    this.selectedLiValue--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement this, too.

Comment: @Dhyey I did same for horizontal, now when the active pointer passes the screen width, it didn't scroll the page. Any help in that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I have implemented this to take care of scrolling it.

```
arrowkeyLocation = 0;
  keyDown(event: any) {
  
    if(event.keyCode=== 13){
     let valueEnterKey =this.serviceDropdown[this.arrowkeyLocation];

     console.log("valueEnterKey",valueEnterKey);
     this.dropDefaultVal1=valueEnterKey;
     this.boolval1 = !this.boolval1;
    }
   
    var listOfDropDownItemsService = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[6];

    if (event.keyCode === 40 && this.arrowkeyLocation < this.serviceDropdown.length - 1) {
      // Arrow Down
      this.arrowkeyLocation++;
      listOfDropDownItemsService.scrollTop = listOfDropDownItemsService.scrollTop + 15;
    }
     else if (event.keyCode === 38 && this.arrowkeyLocation > 0) {
      // Arrow Up
      this.arrowkeyLocation--;
      listOfDropDownItemsService.scrollTop = listOfDropDownItemsService.scrollTop - 15;
    }

   
  }
```